# Passing SOME of the parameters to a function in python

Tags: python

Let's say I have:

```
def foo(my_num, my_string):
    ...
```

And I want to dynamically create a function (something like a lambba) that already has my_string, and I only have to pass it my_num:

```
foo2 = ??(foo)('my_string_example')
foo2(5)
foo2(7)
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) would help with:

```
from functools import partial

foo2 = partial(foo, my_string="my_string_example")
```

Demo:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def foo(my_num, my_string):
...     print(my_num, my_string)
... 
>>> foo2 = partial(foo, my_string="my_string_example")
>>> foo2(10)
(10, 'my_string_example')
>>> foo2(30)
(30, 'my_string_example')
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
>>> def foo(a, b):
...    return a+b
...
>>> def makefoo2(a):
...    def f(b):
...        return foo(a,b)
...    return f
...
>>> foo2 = makefoo2(3)
>>> foo2(1)
4
```

Obviously you can vary the definition of `foo` to taste.